# Conditions on explode function in php

Tags: php

The second condition about the date is working fine, however the first condition is always echoing w, whether the input is wrong or correct. Why so ?

```
$file_name='NZL-00-2015';

list($name_loc, $name_date) = explode('-', $file_name, 2);
if($name_loc != "CAL" || "FLP" || "ARZ") {
    echo "w";}

  else  {
    echo "G";}

$d = DateTime::createFromFormat('m-Y', $name_date);
if($d && $d->format('m-Y') != $name_date){
    echo "wrong";}

  else  {
    echo "good";}
```

https://eval.in/400632

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because `"FLP"` and `"ARZ"` are truthy values, your `if` statement will always be true. I think you mean:

```
if($name_loc != "CAL" && $name_loc != "FLP" && $name_loc != "ARZ") {
```

Or, to have it another way - if `$name_loc` isn't found in an array of values:

```
if(!in_array($name_loc, array('CAL', 'FLP', 'ARZ'))){
```

Comment: worked on the second way thanks

Comment: Because you meant `&&` in your if statement, not `||`.

Comment: thanks for your help i'll accept the answer when the time limit ends